# iOS issue checking if Bluetooth is ON

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I need to check if Bluetooth is On.

I use this code:

```
func startDetectingBluetoothState() {
        if self.centralManager == nil {
            self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: self.workingQueue, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false])
        }
    }

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        let state = central.state
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // notify observers about state change
            self?.stateObservers.invokeDelegates { stateObserver in
                stateObserver.bluetoothStateChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

I start the app on `iPhone X 11.3` (Bluetooth is On in the Settings), then almost immidiatly it enters in `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` with `state == .poweredOff`. So the value is wrong. Then I turn off Bluetooth in Settings, `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` function is not called (because the previous state it detected was .poweredOff), then I turn on Bluetooth and `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` is called with `.poweredOn` value. Then it detects every state change properly. But if I restart the app and Bluetooth is On, it can't detect it again. If during start the Bluetooth is Off, everything is OK.

I have another device `iPhone 6+` `11.2.5`, where everything works as a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement CBCentralManagerDelegate. Below is the sample code which might help you to check the condition -

```
 var centralManager:CBCentralManager!

 in init() or viewDidLoad()
 {
     centralManager = CBCentralManager()
     centralManager.delegate = self
 }

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

  if central.state == .poweredOn {
     print("Bluetooth is connected")
  }
  else if central.state == .poweredOff{
     print("Bluetooth is not Connected.")
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference with code? As I said: in delegate it only returns .poweredOff state

Comment: Have you tried my code. Also have you tried switching on bluetooth once it is off to get the state?

Comment: Yes, I tried your code, it doesn't work with my iPhone X, but it works with my iPhone 6+, but my code works on 6+ too

Comment: Can you please confirm your ios versions on iPhone 6+ and iPhoneX

Comment: iPhone X is 11.3, iPhone 6+ is 11.2.5

Comment: I think the issue might be with ios 11.3. Would suggest you to try following steps and see if it might help you https://www.howtoisolve.com/ios-11-bluetooth-not-working/

Comment: I can upvote ) but it's almost the same code as mine )

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code Working for you

```
 var centralManager:CBCentralManager!

 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This will trigger centralManagerDidUpdateState
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

}

 func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
{
    print("Central Manager did update state")

    if (central.state == .poweredOn)
    {

        self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
    }
    else 
     {
        // Bluetooth is unavailable for some reason

        // Give feedback
        var message = String()
        switch central.state
        {
        case .unsupported:
            message = "Bluetooth is unsupported"
        case .unknown:
            message = "Bluetooth state is unkown"
        case .unauthorized:
            message = "Bluetooth is unauthorized"
        case .poweredOff:
            message = "Bluetooth is powered off"
        default:
            break
        }
        print(message)

        UIAlertView(
            title: "Bluetooth unavailable",
            message: message,
            delegate: nil,
            cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            .show()
    }
}
```

Comment: no, this code returns .powerOff as well for my iPhone X